# ComImport in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

It seems that this Attribute is now mapped to CoCreateInstanceFromApp which filters out the COMs you can create (basically useless - no third party etc).

So I would like to ask if you know some easy way to instantiate COMs already present and registered on the system by using a GUID?

I managed only to do a hack like this (but which is very cumbersome, just to prevent Microsoft to prevent me doing what I always did and had no problem):

```
[ComVisible(true), ComImport,
 Guid("00000001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IClassFactory
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int CreateInstance([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pUnkOuter,
                       ref Guid riid,
                       [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object obj);

    [PreserveSig]
    int LockServer([In] bool fLock);
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(String dllname);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, String procname);

internal delegate int DllGetClassObjectDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid clsid,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppv);

void LoadItDamnit() {
    IntPtr dll = LoadLibrary(path);
    IntPtr proc = GetProcAddress(dll, "DllGetClassObject");

    var getClassObject = (DllGetClassObjectDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(proc, typeof(DllGetClassObjectDelegate));

    int hr = getClassObject(IMYLIB_GUID, IUNKNOWN_GUID, out oFactory);

    IClassFactory factory = oFactory as IClassFactory;

    if (factory == null)
    {
           if (oFactory != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oFactory);
           throw new Exception("Could not QueryInterface for the IClassFactory interface");
    }

    Guid myGUID = typeof(IMyInterface).GetGUID();
    hr = factory.CreateInstance(null, ref myGUID, out oMyObj);

    _obj = oMyObj as IMyInterface;
 }
```

As you see this needs to have the dll in path (or use other APIs to change the current path) for load library and it is a bit too much of tampering to achieve something that should have been available anyway...

If somebody knows of a better way to instantiate any COM object and overcome the limitation of Metro more easily i buy a beer!

Comment: a better question: why do you need com?

Comment: Because i have functionality in some DLL-s that are used by other applications written for the desktop. And before you go further, yes I know that Metro apps can be killed when Microsoft thinks it is right to do it, however I'm not trying to communicate between a desktop app and a metro app, I'm just reusing some functionality already written there to not redo it because I dont have the source code for it. I'm cleaning up as soon as I'm finished.

Comment: My personal opinion about all the limitations they added is: "if a lot of programmers are not skilled enough to write an application that works, it is ok to punish even the ones that are?"

Comment: These comments read like a rant, always a bad way to invite anybody to post answers.  You'll have to use the package manifest.

Comment: And probably it is a rant. Would you please expand on the package manifest? I only found stuff which is not related to my problem, like allowing functionality (nothing related to COM) and extensibility.